# Dropdown lists and Calling from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, selection

I found a model on how to get data from the DB to select the value that was saved to the DB in PHP, however it doesn't work, can someone adviise on the following code?

```
     <?php      
             $tempoSEL = array("","","","","","","","","","");
if($row['tempo'] == "1"){
$tempoSEL[1] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "2"){
$tempoSEL[2] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "3"){
$tempoSEL[3] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "4"){
$tempoSEL[4] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "5"){
$tempoSEL[5] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "6"){
$tempoSEL[6] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "7"){
$tempoSEL[7] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "8"){
$tempoSEL[8] = " selected='selected' ";
}else if($row['tempo'] == "9"){
$tempoSEL[9] = " selected='selected' ";
}
$db = PageDB::getInstance();

?>
              <p>
                <label style="padding-right:28px;">Tempo</label>
                <select name="tempo">
                  <option value="1" <?php echo $tempo[1]; ?>>2 Sec</option>
                  <option value="2" <?php echo $tempo[2]; ?>>5 Sec</option>
                  <option value="3" <?php echo $tempo[3]; ?> selected>10 Sec</option>
                  <option value="4" <?php echo $tempo[4]; ?>>20 Sec</option>
                  <option value="5" <?php echo $tempo[5]; ?>>30 Sec</option>
                  <option value="6" <?php echo $tempo[6]; ?>>45 Sec</option>
                  <option value="7" <?php echo $tempo[7]; ?>>60 Sec</option>
                  <option value="8" <?php echo $tempo[8]; ?>>90 Sec</option>
                  <option value="9" <?php echo $tempo[9]; ?>>120 Sec</option>              
                </select>
```

Comment: Whatever source you got this code from needs to be burned.  If it's a book, throw it in a fire; if it's a website - tell the owner he needs to actually learn to code before he tries to each others.  This "solution" is about as backwards as I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$a=array("","2","5","10","20","30","45","60","90","120");     
$db = PageDB::getInstance();
            echo  '<p><label style="padding-right:28px;">Tempo</label>
                <select name="tempo">';
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.($row['tempo']==$i?'selected':'').'>'.$a[$i].'Sec</option>'
echo '</select>';
?>
```

May be it can help you
**UPDATE:**

```
    <?php 
$a=array("","2","5","10","20","30","45","60","90","120");     
$d=3;
            echo  '<p><label style="padding-right:28px;">Tempo</label>
                <select name="tempo">';
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
{echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.($d==$i?'selected':'').'>'.$a[$i].'Sec</option>';if($d==$i)$a[0]=$d;}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

$a[0] will store the default value

Comment: This works perfectly, but how would I make one of the array values default, eg 10 Sec?

Comment: What do you mean? and don't forget to click the tick given in left side of answer

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, how would I make one of the array values the default selected ?
'code'<option value="1" >2 Sec</option>
<option value="2" >5 Sec</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">10 Sec</option><!-- Default Value when page loads for first time -->
<option value="4" >20 Sec</option>
<option value="5" >30 Sec</option>
<option value="6" >45 Sec</option>
<option value="7">60 Sec</option>
<option value="8" >90 Sec</option>
<option value="9">120 Sec</option> 'code'

Comment: Thanks so much Webtecher ... it's perfect!